# How to use proxy server while scraping a website using scala scraper?

Tags: scala, web-scraping, proxy

I'm scraping a website which contains reCAPTCHA and I want to you proxy server while sending scraping request. For this I've used on Free Proxy Server (**ZenRows**). I'm using JsoupBrowser() and scala (**version 2.13.1**).

**Code:**

```
  val browser = JsoupBrowser()

  val url = "example.com"
  val encodedUrl = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(url.getBytes)

  val apiKey = "d4397c47c636b6666627*****"
  val zenrowsUrl = s"https://api.zenrows.com/v1/scrape?key=$apiKey&url=$encodedUrl"

  val doc = browser.get(zenrowsUrl)
  print(doc)
```

But it is not working. I've seen some other Proxy Servers like **Geonode** and **ProxyEmpire** but I've not tested these as they are paid.

Am I doing it in right way or not?
Which server should I use?

Comment: Well, the point of reCaptcha is to prevent bots and thus scraping.

Comment: Proxy could help only if the site was displaying reCaptcha after several requests - then you could rotate your IP with the proxy every time reCapcha appears. If it's used from the start and the content is unlocked after successful no-bot-test, forget about a simple solution.

Comment: what is the error message?